# Create Case using API via REST - no "Open Case" activity created

Tags: api, civicase, activities, chaining

I'm using the REST interface and the create case API to create a new case. The case is created, but no activities. In particular, no "Open Case" activity is created as I would have expected. No entry is created in the civicrm_case_activity table. As a consequence (or maybe this is just a coincidence), the Case does not show up in search results. If I edit the case, then a Change Case entry is created in the civicrm_case_activity table and the case then appears in search reports.

Do I need to explicitly create an Open Case activity? For example by chaining api.Activity.create json on to the Case create json? Thanks.

CiviCRM 5.10.4
Joomla 3.9.2
PHP 7.0.33

Comment: I assume there is an Open Case activity in the definition of your case type?

Comment: Erik might have a good point. It works for me ok using `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d @foo.txt http://url/sites/all/modules/civicrm/extern/rest.php` with foo.txt containing `entity=Case&action=create&api_key=my-user-key&key=the-site-key&json={"contact_id":"user_contact_id","subject":"test","case_type_id":"housing_support"}`. The url would be different for joomla - mine is drupal.

Comment: Yup. That was it. In fact I needed to include the Open Case activity in the case type and also in its standard timeline. Thank you!

Comment: @ErikH-CiviCooP Would you like to make that your answer, so I can accept it? Otherwise I will write an answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably do not have an Open Case activity configured for your case type.

Answer (score 4):

Answer (thanks to @ErikH and @Demerit): the problem was that the case type did not have an Open Case activity in its standard timeline (presumably I had deleted it). Anyway, I added the Open Case activity to the standard timeline, and subsequently-created cases have been fine.

Comment: glad you found your issue!